# How I can create modal controller or pop up in ionic and from that I want to get individual values?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I am creating modal controller for each input textbox and from modal controller I want to get calculate values. I have created modal controller and done mathematical calculation also. But I can't get value of individually. So, how I can get that values. Can anyone help me please. I am trying so many different ways, but that's not working.
[This is image which I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMxJ7.png)

```html
game.page.html

<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="fixed">Tortoise [1]</ion-label>
  <ion-input class="input" type="text" (click)="modals()" value="{{dataReturned}}"></ion-input>
  <ion-thumbnail slot="end" class="ProfileAvatr">
    <ion-img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNCaBnTOUW7cmqY5fyOudIy0-xl-Tk6LGCGQ&usqp=CAU"></ion-img>
  </ion-thumbnail>
</ion-item>

game.page.ts

const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: PointsModalPage,
  cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
  componentProps: {
    data: Number
  }
});

modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
  if (dataReturned !== null) {
    this.dataReturned = dataReturned.data;
    console.log(this.dataReturned)
    //alert('Modal Sent Data :'+ dataReturned);
  }
});

page-modal.page.html

<ion-content class="mainDiv">

  <ion-list>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button size="small" (click) = "addNumber()"><ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button size="small" (click) = "subNumber()"><ion-icon name="remove-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label>{{s}}</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3" *ngFor = "let n of numberN" (click) = "getNumber(n)">
          {{n}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button expand="block" color="success" size="small" (click)="submit()">SELECT</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button expand="block" color="danger" size="small" (click) = "close()">CANCEL</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>

page-modal.page.ts

 async closeModal() { 
    await this.modalController.dismiss(this.s);
  }

  // submit(){
  //   this.router.navigateByUrl(`/tabs-menu/newgame/${this.s}`);
  // }

  numberN = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
            1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000,
            10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000,
            100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000
            ];
  a;
  sum;
  subEle;
  sub;
  storeArray = []
  NoArr = [];
  finalarr;
  s;
  // @Output()
  // s:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getNumber(n) {
    // this.storeArray = []
    // this.s=0
    console.log('you selected', n)
    this.a = n;
    this.NoArr.push(this.a);
    console.log('Store Array', this.storeArray)
    // this.s = this.a;

    // this.sum = this.a;
    // this.finalarr = n;
  }
  addNumber() {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    // this.NoArr = [];
    this.finalarr;
    this.storeArray = [];
    this.storeArray.push(this.a)

    for (let i = 0; i < this.NoArr.length; i++) {
      this.sum = this.sum + this.NoArr[i];
    }
    console.log('sum', this.sum);
    this.finalarr =this.sum;
    console.log('final Arr', this.finalarr);
    console.log('No Arr', this.NoArr);
    this.storeArray.push(this.sum);
    this.s = this.storeArray.pop()
    console.log('Store Array', this.storeArray)
    // this.s = this.storeArray.pop();
  }

  subNumber() {
    this.NoArr = [];
    this.sub = this.finalarr - this.a;
    this.finalarr = this.sub
    this.NoArr.push(this.finalarr)
    console.log('sub',this.sub)
    this.storeArray.push(this.sub);
    // console.log('Store Array', this.storeArray)
    this.s = this.storeArray.pop();
  }

  close(){
    this.modalController.dismiss()
  }
```

Comment: So your issue is that the data returned from the modal is null/undefined? Because your approach is correct, ie `modalController.dismiss({ // some data})`.

Comment: I got data from modalController, But I want get value for every individually input text box. Right now I got only one value for input text box, So how can I get all input text box value from modalController after calulation done?

Comment: Create a service for doing that, and in service u can declare an array and push values in it and u can set ur rules if u for example have similar things so u need items to be unique so u put ur own rules. And finally u can loop through this array and make the calculation u need. In ur approach ur doing this but ur setting this.storeArray = [] which is causing the array to be cleared on each entry...

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, Now its working for me.